# How to use fully qualified class name as logger name with NLog?

Tags: nlog

I have a generic class:

```
public class GenericClass<A>
{
    private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public void Blah(A a)
    {
        Logger.Info("Test log");
    }
}
```

Used with a simple NLog configuration:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="console" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I would like my log output to look something like:

```
...|INFO|NLogTests.GenericClass<System.String>|Test log
```

Instead, what I see is:

```
...|INFO|NLogTests.GenericClass`1|Test log
```

How can I get logger to use the fully qualified type name instead of the basic name which only displays number of generic parameters?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of GetCurrentClassLogger, you could use:

```
Logger log = LogManager.GetLogger(GenericToString(typeof(GenericClass<A>)));
…
string GenericToString(Type type) {
  var typeName = type.Namespace + "." + type.Name;
  var args = type.GetGenericArguments();
  if (args.Count() == 0) return typeName;

  typeName = typeName.Remove(typeName.LastIndexOf("`"));
  return typeName 
           + "<" 
           + string.Join(", ", args.Select(a=>GenericToString(a)))
           + ">";
}
```

Place `GenericToString` wherever you keep random utility functions / extension methods.

Disclaimer: the function was hacked up right now and might not work, make your computer catch fire, or induce baldness.

Comment: Yes I could do of course, that but I didn't want to have to remember to call that method each time (and have the extra dependency on common utils assembly). A better approach would be if NLog did it as I think the current output is not very useful. I realize there _may_ be a perf hit in the little bit of extra reflection required, but would be nice to at least have the option to turn it on

Comment: @Andrew: while having this built in might be nice, that's something you'll have to ask the NLog developers to do. In the interim, you could replicate the stacktrace sniffing (or copy-paste it from their source) and create an extension method on LogManager.

Comment: @AndrewSmith likely you can write an extension method taking generics, and also call it GetLogger. Inside you use Inerdial's method to create the name. his way you don't have to remember anything :]

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C# 6 & .NET > 4.5, then you can do a neat trick to use `CSharpCodeProvider`:

```
public static class LogManager<T>
{
    public static Logger GetLogger()
    {
        return LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(T).GetFriendlyName());
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static string GetFriendlyName(this Type t)
    {
        using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
        {
            var typeRef = new CodeTypeReference(t);
            return provider.GetTypeOutput(typeRef);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use this extension like this:

```
var logger = LogManager<Dictionary<string, int>>.GetLogger();
logger.Info("logger name contains generic params");
```

And output will be:

```
2016-09-23 13:52:14.6342|INFO|System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int>|logger name contains generic params
```